# persistant http connection to a push server without GCM

Tags: android, ajax, http, asynchronous, persistent

The problem is simple:

1. connect to HTTP server and keep connection open for a few minutes at a time.
2. trigger a callback function *each* time data is received, not when connection has finished receiving all data.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly what you want to achieve, but if you're looking into pushing to android you may want to consider GCM.

Comment: oh if I wanted to push to android I would use GCM, no I want to make an app to tie into a pre-existing push service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the best way was to handle it using a TCP connection (and writing a little code to parse http).

I used a Socket (from java.net.Socket) in a thread, that loops,  sleeps then checks if there is any new data in the buffer.

very light weight, and works perfectly. As I only wanted to retrieve data when the server presents it on the persistent connection, so didn't need any of the http overhead.

did need to fake a http get request to start it:

```
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            pw.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
            pw.println("Host: www.example.com");
            pw.println("");
            pw.flush();
```